# Keys cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

`WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)` is not working.

Error is displayed as Keys cannot be resolved to a variable.

I want to automate enter key in Selenium Web Driver

Please let me know a solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an import statement:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
```

Comment: But after changing the compiler to latest available it is working. Anyways thanks for that.